# Предыдущий маршрут vue-roter

Tags: vue.js, settimeout

Допустим, есть приложение с тремя роутами.
в каждом из них в mounted записан код:
setTimeout(() => this.$router.push(this.address), 2000),
где this.address содержит в себе путь на следующий роут.
Итак, загр. первый компонент, через 2 сек второй, через 2 сек третий. и так бесконечно.
Но мне нужно чтобы после третьего загружался второй, затем первый. Иначе говоря, чтобы компоненты менялись не по кругу, в 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 и тд.
Я подумал, что this.address в комп.2 можно задать зависящим от предыдущего роута.
if ( "неизвестное мне обращение к роутеру" === '/3' {this.address = '/1'})
Так вот как мне обратиться к предыдущему роуту?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1. Заводишь стек истории переходов, и булевый флаг обратного направления навигации; 2. В хуке роутера `beforeEach` по значению флага `false` толкаешь новый маршрут в стек (таким образом, на вершине стека всегда будет предыдущий маршрут); 3. Когда маршруты для прямого перехода закончатся, инвертируешь флаг и начинаешь выталкивать из стека истории по одному маршруту, с переходом по нему. Это все можно зациклить, по условию пустого стека истории снова сбрасывая флаг и заново запуская серию прямых переходов.